# Why are square Bernoulli matrices invertible with high probability?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, random-matrices, bernoulli-distribution

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with entries of $A$ being sampled i.i.d. from $\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is a fixed constant. This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02279.pdf) (2nd sentence below equation (2)) claims that if $m=n$, then $A$ will be invertible with high probability. May I know why this is true for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$, or can anyone point me to a reference/result that states that this is true? I am asking since this claim doesn't seem very obvious to me. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a heuristic argument: consider $A^T A$, or equivalently consider the pairwise dot products. The diagonal entries have mean $n \alpha$ but the off-diagonal entries have mean $n \alpha^2$, so if they're sufficiently close to their mean then the result is invertible. One can also make a more detailed conjecture about the singular values from this and maybe even prove it by writing down some bounds.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is very small and $n=m$ is not large, then the probability of invertibility will not be high, and in particular the probability of at least one zero column or row will be close to $1$.